Where do I find my old /home files after /media/user/Home is remounted to /home?
After reinstalling ubuntu 22.04, I found out that I have duplicate home directory /home which contains my new files and /media/lance/Home which contains my old files.
Link to first problem
After following Quick GUI Fix, I was able to restore my files and directory /media/lance/Home back to /home. However, I can't find the files that were in my /home directory before, but it still occupies space in my / root partition. (91.3% full)


Did you follow the "Clean UP" section and delete the new /home/lance/ folder using the GUI? That folder may be in the Trash. Empty the Trash and see if it helps. If not, try booting from the Installation USB (Try option) and mount the /dev/nvme0n1p2 and as /media/ubuntu/blablabla/ where blablabla is the UUID of the partition. Then navigate to the /media/ubuntu/blablabla/home and see if the lance folder still exists inside.

If I understand the mount command correctly, it overlays (makes inaccessable but not deleted) whatever is at the mount point.
For mount points, I usually make a directory with nothing in it then as needed do the mount command.
Whatever you have at the mount point prior to the mount command will not be accessible.
